# Retrofit2 whit Kotlin

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to read an API with retrofit2 in Kotlin but I can't see why it returns an error. I would appreciate help to understand what the problem is. Thanks.

ApiResponse.kt
...

```
package app.macgo.api.models

data class ApiResponse(
    val bpi: Bpi,
    val chartName: String,
    val disclaimer: String,
    val time: Time
)

data class Bpi(
    val EUR: EUR,
    val GBP: GBP,
    val USD: USD
)

data class Time(
    val updated: String,
    val updatedISO: String,
    val updateduk: String
)

data class EUR(
    val code: String,
    val description: String,
    val rate: String,
    val rate_float: Double,
    val symbol: String
)

data class GBP(
    val code: String,
    val description: String,
    val rate: String,
    val rate_float: Double,
    val symbol: String
)

data class USD(
    val code: String,
    val description: String,
    val rate: String,
    val rate_float: Double,
    val symbol: String
)
```

...

ApiService

...

```
package app.macgo.api.models

import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Url

interface ApiService {
    @GET
    fun getPricesByData(@Url url:String):Response<ApiResponse>
}
```

...

MainActivity

...

```
package app.macgo.api

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import app.macgo.api.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import app.macgo.api.models.ApiResponse
import app.macgo.api.models.ApiService
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val btn = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.btn)
        btn.setOnClickListener{
            callPrice()
        }

    }
    //
    private fun getRetrofit():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    }
    //
    private fun callPrice(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call:Response<ApiResponse> = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getPricesByData("scurrentprice.json")
            val resultado: ApiResponse? = call.body()
            if (call.isSuccessful){
                println("RESULTADO: $resultado")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

ERROR:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: app.macgo.api, PID: 11571
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<app.macgo.api.models.ApiResponse>
for method ApiService.getPricesByData
at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:116)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:67)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy1.getPricesByData(Unknown Source)
at app.macgo.api.MainActivity$callPrice$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:38)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<app.macgo.api.models.ApiResponse>.
Tried:
* retrofit2.CompletableFutureCallAdapterFactory
* retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:272)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:114)
... 13 more

Answer (score 1):

In a plain retrofit interface, use `Call` and not `Response` as the wrapping type.

That is, change

```
fun getPricesByData(@Url url:String):Response<ApiResponse>
```

to

```
fun getPricesByData(@Url url:String):Call<ApiResponse>
```

Comment: interface ApiService {
    @GET
    fun getPricesByData(@Url url:String): Call<ApiResponse>
}

private fun callPrice(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call: Response<ApiResponse> = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getPricesByData("scurrentprice.json").execute()
            val resultado = call.body() as ApiResponse

                println("RESULTADO: $resultado")

        }
    }

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: app.macgo.api, PID: 27612
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type app.macgo.api.models.ApiResponse
        at app.macgo.api.MainActivity$callPrice$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at ...

Comment: I have made the change suggested by laalto, but now it returns a null body. What am I doing wrong?

 private fun callPrice(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call: Response<ApiResponse> = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getPricesByData("scurrentprice.json").execute()
            val resultado: ApiResponse? = call.body()

            println("RESULTADO $resultado")
            if (resultado != null) {
                initCharacter(resultado)
            }
        }
    }